# Show better Javascript console log message with Visual Studio (2015)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

Hello I got a quite simple question. I want to improve the log message that Visual Studio generates. Now if I add to my javascript (.net project) console logs I will see in my output the following result:

```
Log Message: [object Object] from runner.js
```

But I can not check what is inside the array. Is there a tool or something that could help me? I am running JS code inside my .net application via chuztpah (unit test tool).

I tried to use `Debug -> Window -> Javascript console` but this option is disabled for some reason I do not know why.

Comment: Can you use a browser or are you forced to use VS?

Comment: @Johan, yep forced to use VS otherwise I could check the console log window of the browser but I need it inside VS! ;).

Comment: then your best bet would be to do as @ganders suggested.

Comment: @epascarello: Assuming he's using IE at all

Comment: @epascarello does not really matter which IE version! I am fine with a better console message

Answer (score -1):

[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) works very well for this, as I suggested in the comment.

Comment: Unless the object is large, or contains functions.

Comment: You can use the replacer function/parameter to only include the properties that you want, in order to keep the size down.

Comment: `var a=[function(){}];JSON.stringify(a)` --> `"[null]"`. You can't stringify functions.

Comment: I do not think it will work in my case. I will get these errors: `Error: TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures`

Comment: Also that. self-referencing objects can't be stringified. `var a = {}; a.a = a;` is perfectly valid JS, but impossible to stringify as JSON.